# libjpeg: how to get proper image decompressed size?

Tags: c++, jpeg, compression, libjpeg

I have such a usual code:

```
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

cinfo.scale_num = ?;
cinfo.scale_denom = ?;

needed_width = cinfo.output_width;
needed_height = cinfo.output_height;
```

How to pick up **scale_num** and **scale_denum** parametrs to scale the image to ge needed size. I want for example to scale it double smaller.

If i set `scale_num = 1` , `scale_denom = 2` . The result is : (1802 x 1237) to ( 258 x 194)

The documentation says:

```
Scale the image by the fraction scale_num/scale_denom.  Default is
1/1, or no scaling.  Currently, the only supported scaling ratios
are 1/1, 1/2, 1/4, and 1/8.
```

But when i set such proportions i do not get needed results.

So the **question** is:  **How to set `scale_num` and `scale_denom` to get image with maximum similar size to needed.**

Answer (score 4):

You should call jpeg_calc_output_dimensions(cinfo) to obtain correct output_width and output_height values.

to calculate the coefficient scale_denom I usually do something like this:

```
unsigned int intlog2(unsigned int val) {
 int targetlevel = 0;
 while (val >>= 1) ++targetlevel;
 return targetlevel;
}

// ....
// for example, 
const int width = 5184;
const int height = 3456;

unsigned int needed_width = 640;
unsigned int needed_height = 480;

unsigned int wdeg = intlog2(width / needed_width);
unsigned int hdeg = intlog2(height / needed_height);

unsigned int scale_den = std::min(1 << (std::min)(wdeg, hdeg), 8);

unsigned int result_width = width / scale_den;
unsigned int result_height = height / scale_den;
```

Comment: What is your input width and height and needed_width, needed_height?

Comment: 3264 x 2448 to 1024 x 768, as result is 1632 x 1224. But libjpeg can load for example 1224 x 918 for this image.

Comment: You should read the image with 1632 x 1224 (scale_den = 2), then perform resize to desired size